# How to get a specific key from Map object in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, key

I have a map object and I would like to get the value of a specific key ( the value of key it self ) from the Map object 
let say we want to get 'correct'

we can get the values of 'correct' key  by :
 `question.get('correct') // return 3` 
but i want : 
 `someCode //return 'correct'`

```
const question = new Map();

question.set('question','What is the latest version of javasript ?')
question.set(1,'es4')
question.set(2,'es5')
question.set(3,'es6')
question.set('correct',3)
question.set(true , 'correct Answer');
question.set(false , 'wrong Answer')
```

Comment: So you want to get the key based on the value?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen i want something like that : if ( valueOfKey === userInput ) { do somethings }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a key based on a value, you can iterate over map entries using [Map.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) and return the key if found.

```js
const question = new Map();

question.set('question','What is the latest version of javasript ?');
question.set(1,'es4');
question.set(2,'es5');
question.set(3,'es6');
question.set('correct',3);
question.set(true , 'correct Answer');
question.set(false , 'wrong Answer');

function getKey(map, input) {
  for (let [key, value] of map.entries()) {
     if (value === input) {
       return key;
     }
  }
  
  return "Not found";
}

console.log(getKey(question, 3));
console.log(getKey(question, 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the values of keys as follows which will get all the keys of the map object:

```
question.keys();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your use case is just to test the existence of key then simply use `has`, but if you want to get key back if it present else some other value then you can use [`has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has) to test key is present or not, here `getKey` function check if key is present on Map return that key else return `Not found`

```js
const question = new Map();

question.set('question','What is the latest version of javasript ?')
question.set(1,'es4')
question.set(2,'es5')
question.set(3,'es6')
question.set('correct',3)
question.set(true , 'correct Answer');
question.set(false , 'wrong Answer')

let getKey = key => question.has(key) ? key : 'Not found'

console.log(getKey('correct'))
console.log(getKey('randome key'))
```

You can even use `[...Map.keys()]` to get array of keys and then iterator over and find if the value is found or not

Comment: i want something like that : 
if ( valueOfKey === userInput ) { do somethings }

Comment: @HakimBencella what do you mean by valueOfKey, `question.get('counter')` is giving you value of that key and you didn't wanted that right ?, if you just need to check what use passed is present in map or not just use `if(question.has(userInput)){ do something }`

Comment: No , lets say i want `if ( userInput === 2 ) { do something }`
just the key '2' and not all of them

Comment: @HakimBencella `if(question.has(userInput)){ do something }` this will do the same what you're saying

Comment: `if(question.has(userInput)){ do something }` if the user input is '3' it return true and i want it to return true only if the user input = '2' and not '3' ..